# prefix notation c++, segmentation fault (stack and queue)

Tags: c++, stack, queue, postfix-notation

I am trying to figure out why I get segmentation fault, and my guess is that it is in my recursive function, which simplifies a prefix notation operation.

For example:

"m + 4 4" Returns: "+ m 8"

During testing I get a segmentation fault signal:

> Exited with signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

I believe though that the problem lies in my recusive function "Operate"

```
string Operate(stack<string> &S, queue<string> &Q)
{
    S.push(Q.front());
    Q.pop();

    std::string::size_type sz;
    string result = "";
    if (IsOperator(S.top()) == true)
    {
        S.push(Operate(S, Q));
    }

    if (Q.empty() == false)
    {
        S.push(Q.front());
        Q.pop();
        if (IsOperator(S.top()) == true)
        {
            S.push(Operate(S, Q));
        }

        if (S.size() < 3)
            return "wrong input";

        string arg1 = S.top();
        S.pop();

        string arg2 = S.top();
        S.pop();

        string oper = S.top();
        S.pop();

        if (StringIsDigit(arg1) && StringIsDigit(arg2))
        {
            int a = stoi(arg1, &sz);
            int b = stoi(arg2, &sz);
            char o = oper.at(0);

            int c = 0;

            if (o == '+')
                c = b + a;
            else if (o == '-')
                c = b - a;
            else if (o == '*')
                c = b * a;
            else
                return "e";

            result = to_string(c);
        }
        else
            result = oper + " " + arg2 + " " + arg1;
    }
    else
    {
        result = S.top();
        S.pop();
    }

    return result;
}
```

or in the function StringIsDigit:

```
bool StringIsDigit(string arg)
{
    bool result = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < arg.size() && result == true; i++)
    {
        if ((arg.size() != 1) && (arg.at(0) == '-') && (arg.at(i + 1) != ' '))
            i++;
        else
            result = isdigit(arg.at(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Link to the whole program code:
https://pastebin.com/04pfE55N

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: SegFault = post the stack trace to quickly identify the problem

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback! I do not find the case in which my program breaks. But I guess I can continue creating testcases to find where it breaks.

Comment: I think you may be reading outside of the bounds of your string in your `StringIsDigit` function. Your loop condition is `i < arg.size`, and you try to access `arg.at(i + 1)`. Just a hunch--maybe your other condition means it never hits this--but something to look out for in your debugging session.

Comment: Thanks struthersneil! I see the problem, I will check this at once! I will return when I know more :)

Comment: ``std::string::at`` (and the other ``at`` functions) throw an exception when trying to access an element out of bound, it can't cause a segfault. (the out of bound access is still an error)

Comment: struthersneil was correct! i made a simple of by one value in my function "StringIsDigit(string arg)" Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @SebastianLundgren could you add an answer explaining how you resolved your issue ? It may be useful for someone with a similar issue.

Comment: I will submit an answer tomorrow, when I am at the computer. I edited the post explaining the solution, but i see now that I can submit an answer. Thanks for pointing this out to me. Best sebastian

Answer (score 0):

The answer was quite simple, my error: SEGFAULT was as many pointed out for me error in reading from memory, [segmentation fault, wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

**When did the segfault occur?**
It was when my function StringIsDigit() tried to figure out if negative values over 2 characters was an integer. In the "if statement, when checking if the string was indeed an integer, say -100", I continued to read the string until I reached the end of the arg string, but with arg.at(i + 1). Leading to the code trying to access memory outside the string array.Thanks **Struthersneil** for finding this flaw!

Please look at my old StringIsDigit() to find out the of by one value error I made:

```
bool StringIsDigit(string arg)
{
    bool result = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < arg.size() && result == true; i++)
    {
        if ((arg.size() != 1) && (arg.at(0) == '-') && (arg.at(i + 1) != ' '))
            i++;
        else
            result = isdigit(arg.at(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

**The solution**
The solution I want to make sure that the string was an integer since my algorithm supports expressions, such as x+3. This means that I need to iterate through the string is call isdigit() on every character in the string array. Though '-' is not an integer, '-' is needed obviously to express a negative integer, so I made a flawed check as you can see in my old StringIsDigit(). Instead of using that conditional if statement, I checked if the first character '-' and the second is not a whitespace ' ', and then I just let the isdigit() function do the rest of the work.

```
bool StringIsDigit(string arg)
{
    bool result = true;
    //I only need to check if the first is a '-' char and
    //the next char is not ' '.
    for (int i = 0; i < arg.size() && result == true; i++)
    {
        if ((arg.size() != 1) && (arg.at(0) == '-') && (arg.at(1) != ' '))
            i++;
        else
            result = isdigit(arg.at(i));
     }
     return result;
}
```